# How to I copy only specific columns from sql table to Azure data lake storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I previously created a copy activity to copy all columns in sql table into ADLS in parquet format.
I am new to Azure data factory. So my question is how would copy only a specific set of columns into Azure data lake storage as Parquet?

Comment: In copy activity's source settings, in Use query option, click the **Query radio button** instead of table radio button 
and In Query text box, Type the query that selects the required columns

Answer (score 1):

- In copy activity source settings, click the **Query radio button** in Use query option.
- In Query text box, Type the query which selects only the required column.

[image]

- In sink, use the Parquet dataset.
  [image]
- When copy activity is executed, only selected columns from SQL table gets copied to data lake.

**Preview Data of Source**

- When table is clicked in source dataset settings, all columns are selected.

[image]

- When Query option is clicked in source settings, selected columns from the query are displayed.

[image]

Comment: is this approach applicable if the copy activity is embedded in a ForEach Loop activity?

Comment: Yes. You can use switch to Query option even if copy activity is inside the foreach activity

Comment: My challenge is how to dynamically change the query as the query would be different for each table in that for each loop.

Comment: You can use a lookup activity with a table that stores all queries and then connect the lookup activity sequentially with for each activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can even restrict via mapping table and delete unnecessary fields, so that only the selected fields will get copied to the destination file or table of your interest.

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically in copyactivty embedded in a for each activity

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different table on each loop iteration, I assume the list of tables you're parqueting is stored in a control table of some kind?

So add the fields required from each table also to the control table.

| tableName | fieldList |
| --- | --- |
| customer | id, surname, address |
| product | id, brand, sku |

Lookup from this table to obtain the table and field names, be sure to untick firstrowonly.

[image]

Pass the output into your ForEach loop:

[image]

[image]

Finally access the table name and fields in the copy block query:

[image]